# Ajax (xml) vs REST (json) speed isn't what I expected

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, json, web-services

I'm trying to increase the performance of an AngularJS application I'm working on. The application relies entirely on webservices which return XML.

I'm trying to migration some functions from XML to JSON and I've noticed something a little surprising.

The XHR result for JSON requests is smaller but takes much longer, while XHR response for XML is larger but takes far less time. Is this to be expected?

I was hoping to improve results by converting all AJAX calls to REST but the speed I'm seeing is discouraging.

[image]

Comment: Well what is making it slower on the server? It has nothing to do with the clientside.

Comment: No clue, I don't have access to the server unfortunately.

Comment: Well there is nothing you can do to speed it up. It is not the clientside code, it is the serverside code.

Comment: Before you optimise indentify the real bottleneck. You will need a profile of where the time is being spent and then identify the process consuming most then decide on a optimization strategy. REST can be extremely slow compared to a SOAP service if the service implementation on the server is bad.

Comment: Not much you can do, without access to the server.  I'm not surprised that the server can build XML much faster than JSON.  The size of the XML won't matter until it's > 64Kb, so don't worry about it.

Comment: From what I can see here, you're using different libraries to get different responses (JQuery vs Angular). You ought to factor that into your assessment.